# Go to home screen instead of previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I know this question has been asked many times before, but any of the solution is not working and my situation is a little bit different.

I've an `Activity` which can be called from many different Activities. But I want when the user presses back button, instead of previous activity, app should go to Home screen.

One way to use `StartActivityFromResult()` but then I'll have to use it in every calling Activity.

Comment: u can keep button when button presses it automatically goes to hme page... Intent i = new Intent(AccountActivity.this,ContactsActivity.class);                              startActivity(i);

Comment: "But I want when the user presses back button, instead of previous activity, app should go to Home screen" -- since it is rather unlikely that the *user* will want this, why do you think this is justifiable behavior?

Comment: the activity I'm mentioning is the player screen of a music player. I want when the user selects a song from the playlist then app will go to PlayerActivty. But when back button is press from the player then flow will go to either to the home screen or to some other app which user has opened earlier. Hope I have explained the question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can override `onBackPressed()` method as follows. It should work.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..that worked.. but what if for e.g. I was using message application before my application and I log pressed home key and then opened my app. Now if I press back key how can I return to previously opened app (messaging in this eg)?

Comment: If u know the activity name and package of that mail application, you can call that activity from your onBackpressed method.

Comment: I have seen this at other places that this is not recommended.

Comment: @Enigma any reason why?

Comment: This implementation won't change your back stack logical order, great!

Answer (score 4):

And Adding to this question if  you dont want to back your activity where you pressed back button then just a `finish()` below the code.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
     Intent mainActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     mainActivity.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(mainActivity);
     finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply call the `finish()` method on the activity.

Comment: I won't recommend use this approach because 1. Presumably the operation system will call `onDestroy` callback of the activity which will corrupt your back stack logical order. 2. If your activity called by another activity using `startActivityForResult` method, it will call the calling activity `onActivityResult` callback.

Answer (score 2):

Simply if you go to back Home activity than add this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

    Intent intent=new Intent(currentactivity.this,Mainactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}// on back Pressed first add activity where you stand and add activity where you go
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send an Intent directly home. This can be done through setting the action and category of that intent.

Check the documentation on Intent for details.

Answer (score -1):

It is just simple if you have an Activity A and you make 3 fragments like B, C and **Home_Fragment**. Now, if you are in fragment B or C and press back button you want to move on **Home_Fragment** every time.
Then you have to just override the `onBackPressed()` method in Activity A and also when you jump to any fragment, then give a specific **TAG or name**, you will recognize that fragment in Activity A.

I am giving the example that you can easily understand:

***Moving from  activity A to Fragment C***

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new C_fragment(),"xyz").commit();
}
```

or if you are moving from fragment B to fragment C, and on back press, you want to come on Fragment D, do like below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new C_frament(), "xyz").commit();
        ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment C");
    }
});
```

Now you have to just **override the onBackPressed()** method in main activity as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (((C_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("xyz")) != null 
            && ((C_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("xyz")).isVisible()) {

        Fragment fragment = new Home_Fragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home fragment ");

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
      Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
          Intent i = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no HomeActivity class that you can call. Refer to either my post or @android post.