# How to close Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 4 Activities and each one has different objects which can get from server. The main purpose is when I submit final data in activity 4, Activity 1 must be called again. I have tested several methods, backing from D activity to Main activity is easy but I would like to clear all previous Activities too which makes this question different.

[image: App Activity cycle]

At this time I have to close activity B and C. If I just finish activity D and start Activity A in a new intent, the previous Activities are alive and whenever I want to come back from app I can see those activities again. How can I close multiple activities at the same time?

[image: Final purpose]

Comment: After go D to A. You need to go back on D. When user press back button ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go to home screen instead of previous Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807554/go-to-home-screen-instead-of-previous-activity)

Comment: Please check out my solution below in the end, from my own project where I had such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 lines on Activity D can do the magic.**

In your `onBackPressed()` method of `Activity D`.

**Add theses lines**

```
@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {    
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity_D.this,Activity_A.class));
            finishAffinity();
        }
```

> ***FinishAffinity*** will clear all opened Activities. So only Activity A will remained open

Comment: Thanks, The finishAffinity() approach is suitable for >= API 16. It's working but if I want my app works on API < 16 I have to use flags.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** You can close any activity from any other activity by doing this: (Follow the below steps)

**Step1:** Create a static object of each Class before `onCreate()`:

```
public static YourActivityClass activity;
```

**Step2:** Then in your `onCreate()` initialize it:

```
activity = YourActivityClass.this
```

**Step3:** Now you can finish it from whichever activity you want:

```
YourActivityClass.activity.finish();
```

Similarly you can do it for every activity you want to close from any other activity.

**Alternate Method**: Just pass no history in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);  
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The choice of using the solution is upto you. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tested your code, It works. I have to check these codes on several devices.

Comment: @MohsenHatami Okay, You can test in different devices. I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Start Activity A from Activity D with the flags [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to clear the stack when creating the new Activity.

Comment: It's working but there is a little visual difference on some devices by using finishAffinity() or flags.On the other hand finishAffinity() only works on API >= 16.

Answer (score 1):

have u used  the following flag

> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CLASS_D.this, CLASS_A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Intent Flags to clear the Stack ,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);  
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Then the Activity A only will be in the Stack

Comment: It's working but there is a little visual difference on some devices by using finishAffinity() or flags.On the other hand finishAffinity() only works on API >= 16.

Answer (score 1):

Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Intent Flag to start activity A again using -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This flag will clean up B and C from the stack and open A.

Answer (score 0):

for going back from activity D to activity A pass the intent in onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent in = new Intent(Activity-D.this,Activity-A.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus to do that.

Define a event class FinishActivity

```
public class FinishActivity{

}
```

register event in activity B,C

you can use

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
```

in your onCreate method for registering and unregister it in onDestroy 
 by `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)`.
Create one method in your activityB,C.

```
public void onMainThreadEvent(FinishActivity event) {
     finish();
}
```

You can send FinishActivity event by `EventBus.getDefault().post(new FinishAxtivity());`Activity B,C will finish themselves after sending that event.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's a good Idea to use register for this purpose.

Comment: What's wrong?It's okay,it will unregister in onDestroy method.

Comment: Of course,you can startActivityA by clear top flag,or set activityA's launch mode as SingleTask even SingleInstance.

Comment: I just told you another way to do that,which way you want to choose it depends on you,my friend.

Comment: Your solution is good but we always look for easier solution. Maybe flags and finishAffinity have the same way as you used in your codes.

Comment: yes,simplest way,set your ActivityA' launch mode to SingleTask in AndroidManifest.xml.When you startActivityA other activities will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to start every activity using startActivityForResult, and then handling the closing of activities in the onActivityResult callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by different of ways.

1. **Using** `noHistory` flag inside activity declaration on `manifests.xml`

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".Acitivity_B"  <!-- do same with activity c and d -->
       android:noHistory="true"/>
   ```
2. **Using** `startActivityForResult`

   ```
   startActivityForResult(intent,101);

   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 101)
           finish();
   }
   ```